# Combine Three Grouped Select Queries Into One

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

```
--ON TIME PMWO's 

SELECT LOCATION, COUNT(WONUM) AS  OnTimePMWOs
FROM
WORKORDER
WHERE   worktype = 'pm' and actfinish<=targcompdate
GROUP BY LOCATION
--PAST DUE PMWO'S

SELECT LOCATION, COUNT(WONUM) AS PastDuePMWOs
FROM
WORKORDER
WHERE  worktype = 'pm' and actfinish>=targcompdate 
GROUP BY LOCATION

--30 DayForecast- 

SELECT W.location, COUNT(W.wonum) AS Forecast30days
from
workorder AS W
INNER JOIN PMFORECAST AS P
ON W.CHANGEDATE=P.CHANGEDATE
WHERE WORKTYPE='PM' AND P.forecastdate>= GETDATE()+30
GROUP BY LOCATION
```

Comment: What's the environment? What's the purpose? What is a problem? What do you want? What's the question? Talk to us if you want us to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer (all be it just a guess based on the limited question). I'm not a fan of placing CASE statements inside aggregates, but depending on environment, indexing, and data in the included tables, it might perform okay. Please be more involved when posting things.  Show us what you've tried, explain the problem, give samples of data, include the desired output, all that fun stuff. The better the question, the better chance of a good answer. Okay, done on the high horse...

```
DECLARE @Forecast30days DATE

SET @Forecast30days = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 30

SELECT
    wo.LOCATION
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN wo.actfinish <= wo.targcompdate THEN wo.WONUM ELSE NULL END) AS OnTimePMWOs
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN wo.actfinish >= wo.targcompdate THEN wo.WONUM ELSE NULL END) AS PastDuePMWOs
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN pm.changedate IS NOT NULL THEN wo.WONUM ELSE NULL END) AS Forecast30days
FROM WORKORDER AS wo
LEFT JOIN PMFORECAST AS pm
    ON wo.changedate = pm.changedate
    AND pm.forecastdate >= @Forecast30days
WHERE wo.worktype = 'pm'
    AND ((wo.actfinish IS NOT NULL AND wo.targcompdate IS NOT NULL)
        OR (pm.changedate IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY
    wo.LOCATION
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Sorry that i wasn't clear enough when asking. It worked in SQL Server.

Comment: You might be able to just wrap the wo.actfinish with an ISNULL.  Like ISNULL(wo.actfinish,wo.createddate).  Remember to check all instances of wo.actfinish in the query just to be sure.